# Left join not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I written query to get record from main table **tpl_upload_csv_file** and get related record from **tbl_process_csv**. I get all the records but the problem is if i have 1 id from **tpl_upload_csv_file** in **tbl_process_csv** for 5 rows its displaying 5 times. Same record is displaying 5 times.

```
$this->db->select('tbl_process_csv.id, tbl_process_csv.record_no, tbl_process_csv.reason,tpl_upload_csv_file.uploaded_file_name, tpl_upload_csv_file.uploaded_date_time');
$this->db->from('tpl_upload_csv_file');
$this->db->where('tbl_process_csv.process_status', 3);
$this->db->join('tbl_process_csv', 'tbl_process_csv.csv_file_id = tpl_upload_csv_file.id', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('tbl_process_csv.date_of_processing', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
print_r($query->result());die;
return $query->result();
```

My table structure is

> tpl_upload_csv_file :
>
> - id
> - uploaded_file_name
> - uploaded_date_time
> - records_available
>
> tbl_process_csv :
>
> - id
> - csv_file_id   -->(Reference if for table **tpl_upload_csv_file**)
> - record_no
> - process_status
> - reason

Comment: Please post your table structure with field list.

Comment: I have edited my question with table structure

Comment: I'm confused. If you have 5 "detail" records in tbl_process_csv that match the "main" table tpl_upload_csv_file id, then left join is supposed to return all 5.

Comment: But my main table records also displaying 5 times @ourmandave

Comment: Yes, the main table record info is returned with each detail record found. How its displayed is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if any problem occur:

```
$this->db->select('tbl_process_csv.id, tbl_process_csv.record_no, tbl_process_csv.reason,tpl_upload_csv_file.uploaded_file_name, tpl_upload_csv_file.uploaded_date_time');
$this->db->from('tpl_upload_csv_file');
$this->db->join('tbl_process_csv', 'tbl_process_csv.csv_file_id = tpl_upload_csv_file.id', 'left');
$this->db->where('tbl_process_csv.process_status', 3);
$this->db->group_by('tbl_process_csv.csv_file_id');
$this->db->order_by('tbl_process_csv.date_of_processing', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: So whats wrong with the data? what type of data you want?

Comment: if i have id 1 in tpl_upload_csv_file and it has related record of 3 in tbl_process_csv then it should not display 3 times instead of that it should display 1 time and the related record should come in seperate array with this

Comment: Ok so why you are not use 'inner' instead of 'left'

Comment: I used that before but same problem occured so i added left

Comment: But edit ur answer with this $this->db->group_by('tbl_process_csv.csv_file_id');

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->distinct('tbl_process_csv.id');
```

Add this line in your code.

So, you will get distinct records w.r.t `tbl_process_csv.id`

Comment: Still getting same result